# Internet explorer 11 format/ css styling issue. bootstrap c# .net core web app

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am displaying a few paragraphs from my SQL database into my website. The displayed para retains formatting in firefox, chrome, safari, and latest edge but not working in internet explorer. Can anyone tell what is causing this issue and how to rectify it? I am using c# .net core for my web app.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="diag" class="col-form-label">Comments:</label>
     <textarea type="text" class="form-control com" rows="1" max-rows="4" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to fill the text field above. And output in chrome looks like this,

```
"Name: Mike 
 Age: 25 

Name: Sridhar
Age: 32"
```

Above is the output I want, but in Internet Explorer 11 and older version of Edge it looks like below,

```
"Name: MikeAge: 25Name: SridharAge: 32"
```

Answer (score 0):

linebreaks was not working in IE 11 when I used text() function to load data through my jquery. When I used .val() function, line breaks was working fine in jquery.